# Azure Blob : how to separate images and videos

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using ListBlobsSegmentedAsync in my C# code to list all the  blobs.Is there a way i can separate the images and videos from response of ListBlobsSegmentedAsync ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from [this link](https://stack247.wordpress.com/2017/09/09/azure-storage-blob-listing-query-with-search-pattern/). You should be able to optimise the code to do a `yield return` which will return results iteratively and not leave your calling code waiting for all the results to be returned.

```
public static String WildCardToRegular(String value)
{
   return "^" + Regex.Escape(value).Replace("\\*", ".*") + "$";
}
```

Then, using it with ListBlobsSegmentedAsync:

```
var blobList = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(blobFilePath, true, BlobListingDetails.None, 1000, token, null, null);
var items = blobList.Results.Select(x => x as CloudBlockBlob);

// Filter items by search pattern, if specify
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchPattern))
{
    items = items.Select(i =>
    {
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(i.Name);
        if (Regex.IsMatch(filename, WildCardToRegular(searchPattern), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            return i;
        }
    return null;
    }).ToList();
}
```